# Negative values not accepted as numeric for X-axis in R:ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is likely something simple, but I can't work it out.

I am loading a dataset looking like this, but which runs from -50 through to 1500:

```
Name    ExpA    ExpB    -50     -49     -48     -47     -46    -45      -44
sampleA Light   Low     12.326  12.326  12.328  36.979  36.979  24.566  24.652
SampleB Light   High    0.0     9.333   9.3233  37.302  46.628  18.651  18.651
SampleC Dark    Low     0.0     0.0     0.0     13.575  40.725  27.150  0.0
```

I perform a melt on the data:

```
x.melt <-melt(x, id=c("Name","ExpA", "ExpB"))

x.melt
    Name    ExpA    ExpB    variable    value
1   SampleA Light   Low     -50     12.326402
2   SampleB Light   High    -50     0.000000
3   SampleC Dark    Low     -50     14.242440
4   SampleD Dark    High    -50     0.000000
9   SampleA Light   Low     -49     12.326402
10  SampleB Light   High    -49     9.325700
11  SampleC Dark    Low     -49     0.000000
12  SampleD Dark    High    -49     8.792096
...etc...
```

and I want to plot the data. This works fine in every aspect other than the x axis. If I don't include the 'as.numeric()' in the x-axis call then it determines my axis is a discrete variable. My basic code is:

```
p <- ggplot(data=x.melt, aes(x=as.numeric(variable), y=value, colour=ExpA))
p + 
  stat_smooth(method="loess", span=0.05, se=TRUE)
```

Which as you can just about see, starts the x axis from zero rather than the -50. 
[image: ggplot]

Is there a way to correctly interpret the variable column for the axis call?

Comment: can you post your initial dataset using `dput(mydataset)`

Comment: What happens if you try `x = as.numeric(as.character(variable))`? To expand on what I mean, compare `as.numeric(factor(c(4, 2, 3, -1)))` and `as.numeric(as.character(factor(c(4, 2, 3, -1))))`.

Comment: This worked. I'm not sure why it worked, but it worked. If you put it as an answer I'll accept it! Your example shown me why it was interpretting it differently to what I was expecting, but I still don't understand why that would happen

Comment: Ok. I'm answering, but I've changed my suggestion based on what is apparently a more efficient method. Please try it if you have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the column called variable is a factor. When you convert a factor to numeric, you're telling R that you want to replace the value with the index of that value in the factor's levels. For example, let

```
a <- c(3, -1, 1)
b <- factor(a)
b
# [1] 3  -1 1 
# Levels: -1 1 3
```

Notice how it sorts the levels. So when you call `as.numeric`, it will replace any value of `-1` with `1`, because `-1` is the first level, and so on. See this

```
as.numeric(b)
# [1] 3 1 2
```

---

There are ways convert a factor to a numeric vector and preserve the values. An efficient way is to do this

```
as.numeric(levels(b))[b]
# [1]  3 -1  1
```

And to address your specific problem, try

```
p <- ggplot(data=x.melt, aes(x=as.numeric(levels(variable))[variable], y=value, colour=ExpA))
p + stat_smooth(method="loess", span=0.05, se=TRUE)
```